# Ruby String to Date parsing error: can't convert Date into String

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, loops, date

This error doesn't seem like it should be happening.

I have a 2D array:

```
a = [["Person", "20 Mar 2017", "20 Mar 2017", "Party"], 
["Person2", "02/27/2017", "02/28/2017", "BDay"]]
```

I am looping through the array parsing the string dates to Date objects with this code:

```
a.each do |i| 
 i.each do
  i[1] = Date.parse(i[1]) && i[2] = Date.parse(i[2]) rescue i[1] = Date.strptime(i[1], "%m/%d/%Y") && i[2] = Date.strptime(i[2], "%m/%d/%Y")
 end
end
```

When I execute my code I get a type error: `can't convert Date into String`
But I'm not converting any Date objects into Strings and when I parse the strings individually outside of the loop it works but in the loop it throws this error.

I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with the `i.each do`?

Comment: `i.each do` to my understanding executes the code below it for every index inside of the inner array.

Comment: I see now `i.each do` was redundant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with this code:

1. `i.each do` makes no sense;
2. operator precedence matters-

That said:

```
a.each do |i| 
  (i[1] = Date.parse(i[1]) && i[2] = Date.parse(i[2])) \
    rescue (i[1] = Date.strptime(i[1], "%m/%d/%Y") && i[2] = Date.strptime(i[2], "%m/%d/%Y"))
end
```

The more rubyish way of doing that:

```
result = a.map do |i|
  i.map do |e|
    Date.parse(e) rescue Date.strptime(e, "%m/%d/%Y") rescue e
  end
end
```

As @Stefan said in comments, it could be better to mutate the desired indices explicitly:

```
result = a.map do |i|
  i.map.with_index do |e, idx|
    case idx
    when 1..2
      Date.parse(e) rescue Date.strptime(e, "%m/%d/%Y")
    else e
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Okay I will change `i.each do` What does the backward slash after the second line do?

Comment: It tells the ruby parser that the line will continue on the next line. I have updated the answer with more readable snippet, that does not mutate the object inplace.

Comment: Could you explain to me why besides the `i.each do` my code was throwing the error so I can understand what was happening? It looks like your code is the same in your first example except for `i.each do` and the backward slash followed by a new line.

Comment: My code has parentheses around the condition, correcting the operator precedence. Without the parentheses, it is treated as `(a) && (b rescue c)`, rescuing the latter condition only, while the exception is raised in the first one and remains not rescued.

Comment: You should limit the date parsing to indices 1 and 2.

Comment: `i.values_at(1,2).map do |e|`

Comment: @Stefan I do an explicit second rescue for others.

Comment: IMO, it makes the code harder to understand. It's not obvious anymore that indices 1 and 2 contain dates and indices 0 and 4 do not. It could even inadvertently parse non-date values, e.g. `'March Hare'` or `'December Party'`.

Comment: @Stefan agreed, thanks, updated an answer accordingly.